# Magento products not showing up after import, but show up after making a null edit

Tags: import

I have imported 122 products using Dataflow profiles. All of them should show up in the frontend, but they don't. However, when I click edit any of the products that don't show up, *make no change*, and save the product, the Blocks HTML output cache will invalidate. Refreshing it will cause the edited product to show up.

Of course, by my luck, this does not work when you mass-edit the products, or change its status to disabled and then back to enabled from the product list.

How do I make them show up all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to RiccardoT for helping me with this one.

My problem was that the websites for the imported products was set to an empty string by default. Apparently, editing them automatically set the invalid website reference to the currently active one. But you want to do that en masse, so you can do two things.

- Add a column in your CSV file named "website". For each product, set this to the name of the website you're adding them to. If you're using only one website, set it to "base".
- Select all products you want to add to one store and mass-edit their attributes by selecting "Update Attributes" in the little list selection thing on the very top of the list. From there, go to the Websites tab, and select the website you want to add them to. Save your changes.

And walla, you have your products in your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Just run reindex from `System > Index Management`.

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: Cleared cache? Are you using some custom module?

Comment: I cleared all caches while I was at it, and I am not running any custom module except for a theme and a payment module. Neither of them should be capable of causing this.

Comment: I agree. Are you in a multiwevsite Magento set-up?

Comment: I am actually running a more-or-less test environment with only one website and only one store.

Comment: That's weird. Try to export your catalog and try to find differences between working and non working products in your export.

Comment: I compared the ones that did show up against the ones that didn't, and visible products had the website set to "base" and the invisibles had it set to an empty string. I got them all showing up in the sitemap now, but not on the homepage. I'll figure that out myself though, thanks!